# To run two application in node.js on single port

Tags: node.js, npm

I'am beginner of node.js,Sorry if I went wrong

I want to run two .js files on single port in node.js.

I have app.js  and chat.js and want to run them on port 3000.

How can I achieve that.

Comment: You simply can't... why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeBond I want to run two application on my node

Comment: You really need to have two application on the same port or it can be a different port for the second application?

Comment: on same port.If it not possible I will switch on two ports

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to run two application on the same port... Now, if you can run the two applications on different ports without any problem, just do that. Otherwise, you should probably use a proxy, something like [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) and dispatch the request to the right application. It seems a bit odd with two completely different applications but since you did not explain your use case, I don't know what you really need.

Comment: OK.In my case the both applications a differ in their purpose. So I        will switch to two ports.

Comment: It is probably a better solution that trying to keep both applications on the same port.